# adsense drop page load speed dramatically?

Tags: javascript, performance, adsense, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

my website home page load score is 91 that without adsense code
this the code

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- arabsdreams -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="11111111"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

when i add the code the speed score dropped to 41 using [google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
i tried to use the rel="preload" like that and put in header

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" as="script">
```

but ads didn't show up
so the link rel="preload" didn't work with adsense code

so how can i use adsense on my website without dropping load speed

Comment: I don't think you can. Unfortunately at the moment AdSense JS doesn't play well with PageSpeed. We have bunch of work on our side to improve AdSense JS.

Comment: I have a generic "solution" for you, delay the script loading using a "setTimeout". This is my normal response for third party scripts that cause issues. **Beware,** you would have to carefully monitor your ad performance (so A / B test if you have the facility to do so) as I know there are a lot of factors that go into your ad revenue / performance. The other thing to consider is that delaying adsense may make your Cumulative Layout Shift even worse, although there are ways to mitigate that. It is an experiment I have meant to run for a while but had no suitable site to run it on.

Comment: I suppose the question is how many ads do you show and how many are "above the fold", as that would greatly influence potential fixes / ideas on the best balance between speed and revenue. (i.e. you might get a lower CPM or fewer ads shown in one position, but we might increase time on site and pages viewed through faster speeds enough to offset that, it is a careful balancing act).

Comment: @GrahamRitchie i use Auto ads onmy site
this code          <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>